# How to implement google map places autocomplete in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to implement [google map place autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete) api in my application. My code is as below-

```
<body>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&callback=autoAddress&libraries=places"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function autoAddress() {
            console.log('here');
            var input = document.getElementById('auto-address');
            var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
            console.log(autocomplete);
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('auto-address'), 'keypress', autoAddress);

    </script>

<input class="form-control" name="address" id="auto-address" type="text" placeholder="Address Details etc.">

</body>
```

I am trying to give suggestions on addresses on keypress event after user presses each character in the input field like below image in official documentation-

[image]

But I am facing following error in my console-

**Uncaught (in promise),
message: "autoAddress is not a function",
name: "InvalidValueError".**

What should I do to solve this? An example code will be much appreciated for reference.

Comment: 1) This is not the Autocomplete widget, this is the Search Box widget 2) The [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox) has a complete and working example. You're obviously missing something although I haven't tested your code. Maybe the `async` attribute?

Comment: @MrUpsidown is correct, the order of execution is the issue. The async or defer attribute on the script tag will solve this.

Comment: @MrUpsidown I have tried with Autocomplete and Search Box both. Also tried with async method. When I am using async my console shows an error that it can not find any word like 'google'. I am also assuming the issue is related to order of execution as #jpoehnelt said. But I am sorry that still I am unable to sort it out.

Comment: also should I test in a live server? do you guys think the error occurs as I am testing in a local environment?

Comment: Why the `addDomListener` on the input? You don't need that. And your scripts are in the wrong order. Declare your callback function before it *might* be called. Also by not using async and (or) placing your scripts before the rest of your HTML you might be calling `document.getElementById('auto-address')` before that DOM element is even loaded. All basic stuff. Again the docs hold a pretty simple and working example with instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I have found my solution. The issue was in the line-

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&callback=autoAddress&libraries=places"></script>
```

I was following some an example from a blog that I cant remember where it said to use a callback function as the request parameter. When I removed the parameter from the script src I dont know why, but it worked!

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
```

If anyone could explain the reason it would be really helpful for me though.

Comment: While that might work right now in your code, it's the opposite of what you should be doing. Load your scripts in the right order and the callback will work. Place your script tags at the end of your HTML.